# How to use DbContextPool with Singleton?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my application I'm doing integrations using NMS and ActiveMQ.
I have some listeners that are singletons listening to some queues for messages.
Upon receiving a message, the listener should process it and log it on the database.
My `DbContext` is configured using the `DbContextPool` option:

```
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
        services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
        });
```

So, when I try to inject the `DbContext` into my `ActiveMqListener` class, I get the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'MyApp.Data.MyContext' from singleton 'MyApp.Integrations.ActiveMqListener'.
```

How can I get one of the Contexts in the pool and free it once my work is done processing one message? Is there any other recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Where is your `ActiveMqListener` service registration code in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ASP.NET Core DI Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes) documentation:

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

By default `AddDbContext` or `AddDbContextPool` register the `DbContext` as `Scoped` service. You are consuming your `DbContext` in `ActiveMqListener` class which has been registered as `Singleton` service. That's the problem!

**Solution is:** register your `ActiveMqListener` to ASP.NET Core DI as `ScopedService` in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

Note: If you are obliged to use `ActiveMqListener` as `Singleton` then register your `DbConext` as `Singleton` too as follows:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
        }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton); // <-- Here it is
```

Comment: Hi @TanvirArjel, thanks for the answer. I got that part, the problem is that my `ActiveMqListener` MUST be a Singleton, because he is always running in my server, he is not bound to a request (as a scoped service is). Therefore, I cannot have it scoped. Any ideas on how to get a DbContext from the ContextPool dynamically?

Comment: @JoãoMenighin Okay! Do you have any problem of using `AddDbContext` instead of `AddDbContextPool ` as I did not find how to make `AddDbContextPool` singleton?

Comment: At first no. I'm trying to stick to the pool for performance gains. But anyway, wouldn't `AddDbContext` have the same issue since it also is registered as a scoped service? Furthermore, `DbContext` should never be singletons, they should always be disposed carefully. That's why I'm trying to find a way to use it dynamically.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin, okay Let me check further what can I do for you.